# MYSQL select and join multiple where AND clauses from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table of products, and a table for product tags.
Trying to select all the products which have all the tags. So when a user refines their search, they only get the products with all the tags.

**tag**

```
id              PID       tag
------------------------------
0c212c04_Gold   0c212c04  Gold
0c212c04_500g   0c212c04  500g
0c212c04_Coin   0c212c04  Coin
```

Initially I tried an `OR` and `IN`, but that brought back **all** the results. Even if they only had 1 of the required tags

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_tags pt ON (p.PID = pt.PID)
WHERE pt.tag = 'Gold' OR pt.tag = '10oz' AND p.RRP BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000

SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_tags pt ON (p.PID = pt.PID)
WHERE pt.tag IN ('Gold','10oz') AND p.RRP BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000
```

So I tried `AND` which brings back **0** results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_tags pt ON (p.PID = pt.PID)
WHERE pt.tag = 'Gold' AND pt.tag = '10oz' AND p.RRP BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000
```

How do I bring back all the products which has multiple tags of `Gold` and  `10oz` and `Coin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option that relies on condition aggregation and that can handle any number of conditions (just add more conditions to the `HAVING` clause):

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_tags pt ON p.PID = pt.PID
WHERE p.rrp BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING MAX(pt.tag = 'GOLD') = 1 AND MAX(pt.tag = '10oz') = 1
```

NB: if you need more columns from `products`, you would need to add them in the `SELECT` *and* in the `GROUP BY` clause (this will not affect the results of the query, since primary key `product.id` is already part of the non-aggregated columns).

Comment: Thanks GMB, really appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p JOIN
     product_tags pt 
     ON p.PID = pt.PID
WHERE pt.tag IN ('Gold', '10oz') AND 
      p.RRP BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000
GROUP BY p.PID  -- okay assuming PID is unique/primary key
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: This works as well, once I changed `WHERE pt.tag AND` to `WHERE pt.tag IN`.